# Invisible, non existent character blocking running a cmd file when changing text content through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd

> '■s' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The file would immediately open and close when I tried to open it normally, I decided to go into CMD and try to open it through there so see the issue, it came out with what is shown above.

I decided to make a completely identical file, copy pasted everything over and it worked just fine. The properties of the file show zero extra bytes vs the remade one.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yv66vrb5p0l76u6/end.bat?dl=0

Here's a file with the issue, feel free to mess with it.

Comment: At first glance, this looks like an encoding issue. Try changing it to [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), remove the faulty character that now appears, and run it again.

Comment: save you file with coding "ANSI", not "Unicode". (Unicode is the default for notepad, if you didn't change it) Unicode characters are two bytes for each character, cmd can't read that properly.

Comment: Depending on how your unknown PowerShell code writes to file it might need a parameter -Enccoding ascii / default / oem

Comment: Inspect the file with a hex editor (e.g. [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)) to see its raw content.

Comment: Non-answer i know, but: Any reason the file isn't just powershell being executed instead of .bat ? it can do all the same stuff and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell could be writing an extra [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) if you are adding one aswell, since .net (which powershell runs) handles that under the hood, this is a scenario that sometimes happens.

You can sometimes get into trouble when generating text files in unicode, because some mechanism might handle BOM and some might want you to handle it, or 2 steps both "handle" adding the BOM, ending up with 2 of them.

You can check the file in a hex editor and see if it starts with FEFF twice instead of once.